# Identifying JavaScript button on webpage for AppleScript

Tags: javascript, html, applescript

I'm working on a small AppleScript (my first) to login to a website. The relevant code should click the submit button highlighted in the linked screenshot using JavaScript.

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "$('submit-button.btn').click();" in current tab of first window
end tell
```

However, I'm unfamiliar with JavaScript, and am unsure on how to identify the button. When I run the script, the console from AppleScript Editor simply states *Missing Value*.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Stuart

http://i1163.photobucket.com/albums/q551/stu_douglas/ScreenShot2013-12-11at65731PM_zps1e3c8f5d.png

Comment: I've never worked with AppleScript - does `$` refer to jQuery like normal or is that something special? If it's jQuery, you'd probably use the selector `$("#submit")` to target the button by `id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, using getElementById() to get at the button in the form. It's also not dependant on jQuery.

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('submit').click();" in current tab of first window
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tell application "Safari"
    if not (exists document 1) then reopen
    tell document 1
        set URL to "https://cap.mcmaster.ca/mcauth/login.jsp?app_id=922&app_name=AIMS"
        delay 3
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('user_id').value='abc';
document.getElementById('pin').value='123';
document.getElementById('submit').click();"
    end tell
end tell
```